# Getting data to print from a function assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// make object properties private

var Bike = function() {
    var speed = 100;                  // private variable

    function addUnit(value) {         // private function
        return value + "KM/H";
    }

    this.getSpeed = function () {     // public function
        return addUnit(speed);
    };
};

var myBike = new Bike();
console.log(myBike);
```

I'm doing the 'Free Code Camp" thing and this is one of the exercises. Other than the `console.log(myBike);` this is the solution to their exercise. However, printing out the data isn't part of the exercise and I like to print out the data. So I'm running this code in node.js and I can't get the data to print. When I run my file I get `{ getSpeed: [Function] }`. What I think it should be is `100 KM/H`. Could someone show me how to print out the data?

Comment: Use Firebug for Firefox, if you want the better Object details. You are `console.log`ing the entire Object. To get the value you should `console.log(myBike.getSpeed())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myBike` is an object of type `Bike`, so what you're printing is actually the instance of your "class" called Bike, you need to do

`console.log(myBike.getSpeed())`

which is to say "invoke the getSpeed method which exists on my Bike object"